# Is there a way to "manufacture" a 4-bits ASLR?

Tags: c, mingw, aslr

I'm currently testing some exploits on a little program I wrote, and would like to know if there was a way of "coding" an ASLR-like protection - or just using some compilation tricks to manufacture it - with restricted possible offsets values (like 16).

What ASLR is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Also, if this can be of any help, I'm using i686-w64-mingw-gcc to compile my sources, maybe there is already an option for that (but I didn't find one).

Thank you !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to make the program add a random offset to the addresses of .text, .data and stack sections - if possible with independent offsets for different sections - on each run.
But I want to keep the offsets fairly small (like between -7 and +8), so I don't want to use linux built-in ASLR.